# ExternalDefinitionCreationOptions Changes from Revit 2021 to 2023

Tags: revit-api

Quick & simple question. What it the updated method to create new external definitions for Revit 2023? upgrading to 23 & says ParameterType is inaccessible due to it's protection level. Wasn't an issue in 21.

`var ExternalDefinitionCreationOptions1 =new ExternalDefinitionCreationOptions("TPFullFabricationServiceName", ParameterType.Text);`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this was deprecated & found the answer here. https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2021/04/revit-2022-sdk-and-the-building-coder-samples.html#6